# how to install vlc 2.0 on ubuntu 15.04

Tags: software-installation, vlc

I am having some issues with vlc 2.2 on ubuntu 15.04. I want to know how to install older version 2.0. I tried installing by using deb package but got lots of dependency errors.

can anyone suggest better method?

Comment: Short answer is: you compite it. But, what issues are you having?

Comment: @xangua if i skip a part of video by clicking on slider, I dont hear audio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's a newer version of vlc that may have the issue fixed:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:videolan/master-daily
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

Also, if you still experience issues, it may help to go to software-center, add all the extra, universe, contrib, etc repos, and then:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

Comment: I am getting error in second command from top

Comment: @edwardtorvalds please post the error

Comment: error is [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/11700152/) thanks for helping me out

Comment: @edwardtorvalds i'm sorry, there's just too many dependencies needed, have you tried using parole media player or xine? both of those usually work well.

Comment: @edwardtorvalds or, have you tried this ppa:videolan/master-daily? here is version 3.0

Comment: I live vlc because it consumes less cpu compared to the one that comes by default in ubuntu. also vlc is good at playing little corrupt videos

Comment: @edwardtorvalds i tried building the older version on 15.04 from source and can't seem to get it to compile even after patching the configure.ac file it fails on make. I'll go ahead and add instructions on how to install version 3.0 instead and hopefully the issue you were experiencing will be fixed.